# Hard or Solid state disk for a 10-years-old motherboard

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, motherboard, sata, asus

I have M4N68T-M LE V2 ASUS motherboard with 4x Serial ATA 3Gb/s. The MB is ten years old. Its old 300GB SATA disk just died and I would like to buy a new 1TB SATA HD or even a 480 GB SSD. Any way to be sure that my MB would work just fine with any of them?
Thank you!

Comment: If the machine supports SATA then you could use either a SATA HDD or a SATA SSD.  Due to the motherboard only supporting SATA II you will see a performance penalty with either option.

Comment: It is true that with an SSD you will see a performance penalty compared with an SSD on a motherboard having SATA 3 ports, but you will see a very considerable performance improvement compared with your old 300 GB hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Empirically - being the owner of several machines with both 3 & 6Gb/s connections - there is very little **practical** difference.

An SSD itself will make night to day performance improvements, even on 3GB/s SATA II, compared to an HD.